# tool to crop and save

Tags: image-processing

I need a tool that helps me to crop and save cropped image easily. I am working on a project that extracts special characters from documents and I need crop character by character and save it with its name. 
My question is how to crop multiple selections at once into several images. I want to select each frame of the document and export them as individual images and do multiple exports at once. Do you have any suggestion how can i do this?

note: It would be preferable if it is work on Mac

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the famous [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) which is also available as [Ubuntu package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=imagemagick) or for [MacOS](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx).
It has a lot of options to *crop* an image, described [in its documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/).

Comment: ImageMagick work through the command line right? I need to select the parts so a tool with interface is needed. but thank you